# how to handle new button in submit_line.html in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-admin

i already create a class to validating xml file, and i try in actions its work but how i can make the script work in new button i create in submit_line.html

this is my admin.py with actions

```
    class CrsFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('fi', 'file', 'import_datetime', 'state')
    readonly_fields = ('state','import_datetime','log')
    actions = ['some_action','Validating']

    def Validating(self, request, queryset):
        for crsfile in queryset:
            xsdfile = etree.parse("/home/.../.../.../ex.xsd")
            xsdpar = etree.XMLSchema(xsdfile)
            xmlfile = etree.parse(crsfile.file.path)

            result = xsdpar.validate(xmlfile)

            if result == True:
                crsfile.log = "Validate: Successfully validate"
                crsfile.state=CrsFile.CHECKED
                print("valid")
            else:
                crsfile.state=CrsFile.ERROR
                crsfile.log = xsdpar.error_log 
                print(crsfile.log)

            crsfile.import_datetime=timezone.now()
            crsfile.save()

        self.message_user(request, crsfile.log)
        return crsfile.log

    Validating.short_description = "XML Validate"

admin_site.register(CrsFile, CrsFileAdmin)
```

and this new button i create in submit_line.html

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}

#NEW SUBMIT BUTTON
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'IMPORT' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
</div>
```